# How to use Plus Character in Camel JMS Selector Option?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to create a JMS selective consumer in Camel (Using Talend ESB) and I have a selector which I think should work, except that because it is being URL encoded, the plus (+) character is being replaced by a space.

So I have

```
selector=Type <> 2 AND Date <= ( getDate() + 10 )
```

which generates an error that it can't setup the destination with the cause:

```
Type <> 2 AND Date <= ( getDate()   10 )
```

so the `+` character has been replaced by a space.

Following the advice of the manual that some characters have to be encoded, I replaced the `+` with `%2B` but that resulted in the identical error message, so even my encoded `+` has been replaced by a space.

How do I encode this selector such that the plus is not replaced by a space?

Thanks! Screwtape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to configure it as **RAW value** as described on [this docs page](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html) for a password

```
.to("jms:queue:yourQueue?selector=RAW(your selector)")
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine, but interestingly still warns me that "Supplied URI ... contains unsafe characters, please check encoding.". When I encoded the + character as %2B, it still gave the same message having decoded the %2B to a plus.